# Angular UI-Router nested tabs, switch and switch back to where we left off

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Please look at [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUbCR8?p=preview)

1. click "Left"
2. click "Link 2" to expand it
3. click "Right"
4. Click "Left" - link 2 is no longer expanded

Question: how can the Left tab "remember" that it was displaying "Link 2" when we tab away from it and then return to it? (I want to do this for the Right tab too, of course)

Please note that I do not want to hack the official Angular (UI-Router, etc) code in any way.

Also, I would like it so that Link 1 gets expanded by default the first time that Left is displayed or selected (with a similar default on Right). But that may be a subject for a separate question?

Comment: You might wanna see [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/562) and [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/894).

Comment: Why don't you just store the expanded state in a more parent controller?

Comment: Because I don't how how. I'm a n00b  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily.

Set up separate states for each tab at the same level

1) Register a $stateChangeSuccess listener on `$rootScope`.  If the to state `.includes("left")` or `.includes("right")`, then keep track of the destination state and its stateParams.

2) Register a $stateChangeStart listener on `$rootScope`.  If the to state `.is("left")` or `.is("right")`, then prevent the transition directly to the tab state, and then use `$state.go` to the state/params you saved earlier for that tab.

Have a look at my ui-router fork which implements this.  I call it "deep state redirect". 
https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router/blob/issue-894/src/parallelState.js#L32

I made a plunk and integrated the scope listeners and registry from my fork to the root scope in the plunk.  Have a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/2EDS21yD6ygI5nHMFu0H?p=preview

Comment: +1 (bit not the answer, yet). I love it! You have obviously done a great deal of work. The Plunk shows exactly what I want to happen, **but** I am concerned abut that UI-Routr fork. Is there no way to do it with standard, non-forked Angular?

Comment: You don't need the fork.  You just need a place to put the registry and listeners.  I added a plunk to my answer with the concepts implemented on the root state's controller.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying. Something came up. I do like your Plunk, insofar as I can understand it. However, when I try to apply it to my already existing app, with 3 tabs, each of which has a further two tabs (nested controllers), by putting `$scope.deepStateRedirect.register('top.<controller name>');` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing how you structured your app, but the error message indicates that deepStateRedirect service object is not on the $scope you are using.  Is the $scope you are accessing a child scope of the one you put the deepStateRedirect on?  In the controller you are adding the deepStateRedirect to $scope, you could perhaps add it to $rootScope instead to avoid parent-child confusion.